# parsing dates with month without leading 0

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I'd like to parse dates consisting of month (1-12) and year like eg:

```
1.2015
12.2015
```

into `LocalDate`

I get an exception using this code:

```
final DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M.yyyy");
LocalDate monthYearDate = LocalDate.parse(topPerformanceDate, monthYearFormatter);
```

*java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '6.2015' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=6, Year=2015},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed*

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) ist not clear for me on the short month format.

**edit:** I guess the problem is the missing day of month?

Comment: I'm not Java expert, but what day of month do you expect in parsed date?

Comment: I hoped the day of month would be undefined...

Comment: How would you like later to use such dayless date?

Comment: Then you don't really have a date.

Comment: I'm forward and backward to all involved Classes here and the only think I can find is, how should the Day be handelt here. Because the date is only fullfiled by providng day, month and year. I would try to add alsways the first to your date string and format.

Comment: @Pshelmo, i need to get the first and last date of the parsed month-year and later call monthYearDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()) and monthYearDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your input is not a date but rather a month/year combination, I would suggest using the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class:

```
String input = "1.2015";
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M.yyyy"));
```

In the comments you add that you need the first and last day of the month:

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay(1);
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem is really the missing day of month. My workaround is to set it:

```
    final DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.yyyy");
    month = LocalDate.parse("1." + topPerformanceDate, monthYearFormatter);
```

Comment: I don't think setting an arbitrary day of month is the clean way to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

LocalDate  represents an actual date  , so you can not use just a year and a month to get LocatDate

you can use

```
 YearMonth yearMonth =YearMonth.from(monthYearFormatter.parse("6.2015"));
```

and  you can format the month str to 0x before format it  and use MM.yyyy  pattern to format

Answer (score 1):

I can't find exactly definition of the behavior in the docs. But my guess is that you need a Day to fullfill the temporal object LocalDate.

Try this:

```
final DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.yyyy");
LocalDate monthYearDate = LocalDate.parse("1." + topPerformanceDate, monthYearFormatter);
```

Answer (score -2):

there are only two cases, why don't you just try them both?

```
final DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.yyyy");
final DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M.yyyy");

LocalDate monthYearDate;
try{
    monthYearDate= LocalDate.parse(topPerformanceDate, monthYearFormatter1);
}catch(DateTimeParseException e ){
    monthYearDate=LocalDate.parse(topPerformanceDate, monthYearFormatter2);
}
```

Comment: Tried them both, even L.yyyy, got an exception in all cases.

Comment: @kosmičák hmm ok, it seems u fixed it by adding the day... strange